# My Multithreading code with C++ is not working properly

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <cctype>
#include <chrono>

#define MAX_THREADS 3

std::string file_path = "metin.txt";
int total_words = 0;
int total_sentences = 0;
int total_paragraphs = 0;

std::mutex lock;

void count_words() {
    std::ifstream file(file_path);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Dosya açılamadı." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int words = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = file.get()) != EOF) {
        if (std::isspace(c)) {
            words++;
        }
    }

    lock.lock();
    total_words += words;
    lock.unlock();

    file.close();
}

void count_sentences() {
    std::ifstream file(file_path);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Dosya açılamadı." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int sentences = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = file.get()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '.') {
            sentences++;
        }
    }

    lock.lock();
    total_sentences += sentences;
    lock.unlock();

    file.close();
}

void count_paragraphs() {
    std::ifstream file(file_path);
    if (!file) {
        std::cout << "Dosya açılamadı." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int paragraphs = 0;
    char c;
    while ((c = file.get()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            paragraphs++;
        }
    }

    lock.lock();
    total_paragraphs += paragraphs;
    lock.unlock();

    file.close();
}

int main() {
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // Başlangıç zamanı

    std::thread threads[MAX_THREADS];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            threads[i] = std::thread(count_words);
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            threads[i] = std::thread(count_sentences);
        }
        else {
            threads[i] = std::thread(count_paragraphs);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }

    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // Bitiş zamanı
    auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time); // Geçen süre

    std::cout << "Toplam kelime sayısı: " << total_words << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Toplam cümle sayısı: " << total_sentences << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Toplam paragraf sayısı: " << total_paragraphs << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Programın çalışma süresi: " << elapsed_time.count() << " ms" << std::endl; // Geçen süreyi ekrana yazdır

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code that calculates using multithreading to find the number of words, sentences and paragraphs in a file. This code reads the datas from a file called "metin.txt" (You can think of the data as a long text.) and calculates using a separate thread for each function (feature). I used 3 threads in total. But I guess my threads are not running synchronously (simultaneously). I feel it is running sequentially and I couldn't figure it out. Can you help me ? How can I design this code to run all of my threads at the same time? And also what can I add to improve the code further and if the code does not suit the logic of the thread structure in this way, What can I change to fit this logic? **(I am running on linux operating system for this code).** I'm not completely familiar with this topic, sorry if I asked the wrong question.

Comment: Why do you think the code is not running all 3 threads at the same time?

Comment: I made the non-threaded version and it ran that program for about the same time. it is need to spend less time than non-thread

Comment: Does your text file have millions of words?

Comment: I don't know if I'm thinking wrong.

Comment: yes there are about 31 million words

Comment: You could easily check the speed difference by joining each thread after creating it. That way you get the serial speed.

Comment: I dont understand sorry for my bad english. Can you explain clearly please

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: can you upgrade my code and share with me please. If is it possible

Comment: Add to the post how you arrived at the conclusion that the threads are not running parallel.  A comparison of timing measurements for sequential ('join' after each thread created) vs parallel (as the code posted).  Also your mutex is not necessary but should not be adversely affecting timing.

Comment: Has it occured to you that you can prove or disprove your hypothesis in a very trivial, simple way, simply by having each one of your three functions print a message at the beginning, and just before it returns, and then seeing what kind of output you get?

Comment: You read the same file in 3 threads. I doubt performance of reading it thrice would improve with such a crude parallelization, though it might depend on hardware. That you parallelized it doesn't imply you'll improve performance. Try incrementing a single atomic variable a billion times - doesn't matter how many threads do it.

Comment: Can someone edit this code please ? I am new in this topic

Comment: To test serial performance time place `threads[i].join();` after `threads[i] = std::thread(count_words);` and also after `threads[i] = std::thread(count_sentences);` and also after `threads[i] = std::thread(count_paragraphs);` then comment `threads[i].join();` out in the next for loop.

Comment: A note about the title: *My Multithreading code with C++ is not working properly* Doesn't contain much useful information for future askers. Please try to provide descriptive titles. Ask yourself, "Would I click the link if I saw this title in a list of search results?" if the answer is no, rework the title.

Comment: Okay. I will try to do your suggestions

Comment: I tried to do printing operation for the see what happens to each function. And then I think it is working paralelly for each threads. But I dont know. I am not sure. How can i do serial working each thread and how can i measure to time.

Comment: Here all 3 threads need to load the file. The cost of testing is negligible compared to the work of loading the file. The 3 threads do pretty much the same thing and have about the duration of a 4th thread doing the 3 lookups. **Here, threading is not the way to save time**.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the problem might be with your mutex.
It serialises all your threads.

As I understand, these threads don't share any data they write to. So, you can remove the mutex from your code.

Edit:
If your threads do share data they write to, you need to redesign your code.

Another problem might be thread initialization time
Check how much time each function takes to complete and compare it to your total execution time in serial and parallel code.
Try to increase work each thread do.

Another possibility is that one of your functions take much more time to finish, than another. You just wait that function and your code doesn't gain anything from parallelization.